# Possible to add multiple language variants to projects in the same workspace?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I'm in the process of setting up projects and training engines in a workspace.
I want to create all the projects using the same metadata so that they will all share the same Category ID (so they can all be called from the same TMS workflow).

However, it won't let me set up projects that share the same language pair from the drop-down, even if the project names are different (e.g. Project_fr-fr, Project_fr-ca).
This is a blocker because, for example, the drop-down only has English>French, while I have projects with fr-fr and fr-ca as target.

Any workaround suggestions welcome.

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 0):

Language pair must be unique under the same workspace to know which custom model to use during the translation time. When you create Project_fr-ca, add label to add uniqueness. So, fr-fr endpoint (category id) would look like -, and fr-ca would be --.

-ME